# T-SQL sorting by a calculated column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with these columns: `ID, Price, IsMonthlyPrice`

How can I select all and sort by weekly price, taking into account that:

```
if (IsMonthlyPrice = false) then Price is weekly
```

EDIT:

I need to sort by weekly price

weekly price of a monthly price would be: Price*12/52

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some sample data and expected output. I guess you want to do some calculation from price per week to price per month. If so, how many weeks are there in one month?

Comment: What do you mean "taking into account"?  Do you mean that you only want records where "isMonthlyPrice = false"?  Or you want Weekly First, then Monthly?  Also, what datatype is that field really?  (There is a BIT type, but that does not accept 'false' as a value)

Comment: I want to select all and order by weekly price. But some of the prices are stored as monthly and some are stored as weekly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to include the calculation twice. You can order on the column number

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Price, 
    IsMonthlyPrice, 
    CASE IsMonthlyPrice
    WHEN 1 THEN Price * 12 / 52
    ELSE price
    END
FROM [TABLE]
    order by 
        4
```

Comment: Better to give the column an alias and `ORDER BY alias`

Comment: Ordering by number worked perfectly. Exactly what I needed as well.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you look for but maybe try:

```
select 
    id,
    case isMonthlyPrice when 'false' then (price*52/12) else price end normalizedPrice
from
    yourTable
order by
    normalizedPrice
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort calculated columns using two approaches. The more verbal approach (untested pseudocode) is:

```
select ID, CASE WHEN IsMonthlyPrice = 0 THEN Price * 52 / 12 ELSE Price END AS Price
ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsMonthlyPrice = 0 THEN Price * 52 / 12 ELSE Price END
```

The more concise approach is:

```
select * from
(
select ID, CASE WHEN IsMonthlyPrice = 0 THEN Price * 52 / 12 ELSE Price END AS Price
) as derived
ORDER BY derived.Price
```

Comment: I just tried without the alias, worked great. Strange how I just do that out of habit. Was there a point in SQL Server's past or are there scenarios where it is necessary to repeat calculations in the order by clause?

Comment: `ORDER BY` is the only place you can re-use the alias and you can't use the alias within an expression in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I generally wrap the select in a another one. then the column is no longer "calculated"

```
select 
    Price,
    ID
from 
(select 
        ID,
        Price,
        [calculate the IsMonthly Price] as 'IsMonthlyPrice'
    from table
) order by IsMonthlyPrice
```

Comment: I might not have gotten your case entirely correct, but the theory is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` to calculate different values depending on whether the price is weekly or monthly.

This will calculate an approximate (assuming 31 days per month) price per day to sort on:

```
select ID, Price, IsMonthlyPrice
from TheTable
order by Price / case IsMonthlyPrice when 1 then 31.0 else 7.0 end
```