# Stored Procedure with "ORDER BY" dynamic calculation

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a store procedure written and i want to do a calculation in the last "ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC;" statement. In the sense, in the query at "ORDER BY", i want to be able to add minutes from a column in the DB to `DateTime`.

So the idea will be like "ORDER BY variable=(`DateTime` + 15 * 'offsettime") DESC;". I hope there is a work around and someone could help me with this as im not a database expert. Thank you in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591526/t-sql-sorting-by-a-calculated-column

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 YOUR COLUMNS, (DateTime + 15 * 'offsettime') calculation
FROM YOUR_TABLE order by 2
```

## Updated:

Since your requirement is to extract minutes from datetime and do the arithmetic operation, there is a EXTRACT function in Oracle which may help you

```
     SELECT 
     YOUR COLUMNS, (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM DateTime) + 15 * 'offsettime') 
     calculation FROM YOUR_TABLE order by 2
```

Note: Here am assuming your db is Oracle since you didnt talk about it.

Comment: "offsettime" is a coloumn in the database table which has values. Those are in minutes and i need to add them to minutes DateTime. Is this possible?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Most versions of SQL support the standard, where you can include a column alias from the `select` statement in the `order by` clause.  So, if you have:

```
select t.*, (DateTime + 15 * offsettime) as variable
from t
order by variable desc;
```

In addition, pretty much all versions of SQL allow you to have a calculation in the `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (DateTime + 15 * offsettime)
```

Finally, I'm not sure what you mean by `'offsettime"`.  You don't need any quotes around a column name.  If you include them, they should be double quotes rather than single quotes.  Single quotes signify a string constant.

Comment: "offsettime" is a coloumn in the database table which has values. Those are in minutes and i need to add them to minutes DateTime. Is this possible?

Comment: @PavanWelihinda . . . How you add times to a datetime is database dependent.  I assumed that the arithmetic in your question works for the database you have in mind, because you did not tag the question with the database.

Comment: My datetime stamp is in "2012-05-30 18:27:14" format. By doing how you showed, can add the minutes accurately?